# How many different possible permutations are there with k digits that add up to n?

Tags: combinations

So for example:

How many permutations are there with 3 digits that add up to 4? For this question I just list all possible solutions:

004, 013, 022, 031, 040, 103, 112, 121, 130, 202, 211, 220, 301, 310, 400

but what if the number of digit (k) is really big or the sum (n) is big?

k=10, n=71 or k=8, n=62

I looked at some stars-and-bars problems but I feel like it is not applicable in this case. I really do not know what to do...

Comment: Do you really mean **digits**?  For example $62=0+0+0+0+0+0+2+60$ is not allowed?

Comment: oh... no. . It is not allowed. It has to be a digit. so there is a limit for each digit.

Comment: Allocating units to digits, it's straight stars-and-bars until $n$ reaches $10$, Then you have an added constraint of maximum $9$ units per digit.

Comment: @Joffan sorry I still don't understand how it works... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocating units to digits, it's straight stars-and-bars until $n$ reaches $10$ - there will be ${n+k-1 \choose n}$ options. Each digit position is a class, and increments are added to each, so you need to find the classification options.

For example in the $k=3, n=4$ that you worked in your question, the possibilities are ${6 \choose 4} = 15$ (happily matching the cases you found).

Another example, $k=5, n=8$ would have ${12 \choose 8} = 495$ options.

For $n \ge 10$, you have an added constraint of maximum $9$ units per digit so you would need to subtract these outcomes away from the simple formula above. Each time $n$ reached another multiple of $10$ the adjustment would become more complex to account for the potential for multiple digits breaking the $9$-limit simultaneously.

As a relatively simple example in this case, take $k=5, n=12$. Then the previous calculation gives ${16 \choose 12} = 1820$ options, but some of these would imply digit values greater than $9$ . To find this excess  we can preallocate $10$ units to one digit position and recalculate how many of these constraint-breaking options we make with the remaining $2$ units: ${6 \choose 2}= 15$. So the answer here involves removing those options for each digit, $1820 - 5 \times 15 = 1745$ valid options.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the example of $k=8,n=63$, and see what we can do

**Method I, generating functions**

Each time, we generate $0\;thru\;9$ Let us write it as $(x^0 + x^1+ x^2 + .... +x^9)$

Then $(x^0 + x^1+ x^2 + .... +x^9)^8$ represents generating such numbers $8$ times,

and the coefficient of $x^{63}$ when we multiply it out will give the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+x%5E63+in+(1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E9)%5E8), $11,440$

**Method II, stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion**

We use the stars and bars method, and exclude "bad" results by deliberately allowing $10$ in one or more of the $8$ slots. Here it would lead to

$\binom{70}7 - \binom81\binom{60}7 + \binom82\binom{50}7 - \binom83\binom{40}7 + \binom84\binom{30}7 - \binom85\binom{20}7 +\binom86\binom{10}7 = 11,440$

**Method III, stars and bars, attempting to eliminate inclusion-exclusion**

Assume you have placed the maximum $9$ in each slot, (thus $72$ for $8$ slots),

now **take out** $72-63 = 9$ units, applying stars and bars.

We get $\binom{9+8-1}{8-1} = \binom{16}{7} = 11,440$

*We may not be totally successful in eliminating inclusion-exclusion*, e.g. in your example with $k = 8, n = 62$, we would have to use it on a minor scale, $\binom{17}7 - \binom81\binom77 = 19,440$

Comment: +1 I think our two answers work well together, Ch1 and Ch 2 :-)

Comment: idk whar's the logic of accepting but not upvoting. Cheers! (+1)