# Number of ways of picking n numbers between 1 to m such that their sum is k

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any general formula for the following problem? (Repetition of numbers is allowed).

> How many ways can $n$ numbers be chosen, each of which is between $1$ and $m$, such that the sum of the $n$ numbers equals $k$?

Comment: Look at "generalized partitions"

Comment: @Peter are u talking about generalized partitions of graphs?

Comment: Graphs are unrelated.  An easy way to see the answer if you have calculator software handy is to look at the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^m)^n$

Comment: No, partitions are sets of numbers summing up to a given number, for example the partitions of $5$ are $5=4+1=3+2=3+1+1=2+2+1=2+1+1+1=1+1+1+1+1$

Comment: @JMoravitz This is sufficient to determine the number of (generalized) partitions ?

Comment: So, a question I would have is whether you allow order of the numbers to matter, or if the numbers must all be in descending order.  If order of numbers matter, in addition to the partitions @Peter mentions you would also have each of the above in their alternate orderings, $1+4, 2+3, 1+3+1, 1+1+3,\dots$ as well

Comment: @Peter the generating function I mention would indeed count the number of integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n = k$ where $1\leq x_i\leq m$ for all $i$., noting that in my interpretation, $(3,1,1)$ is considered a different outcome than $(1,3,1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz OK, I understand.

Comment: then for n=4 ,m=5, k=10, what should be the answer?

Comment: @Goku95 [The coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5)%5E4)

Comment: Somewhat related, where $m$ is $9$ (and lower limit is $0$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007216/how-many-different-possible-permutations-are-there-with-k-digits-that-add-up-to/2007311#2007311